# Is there an PHP function to get values from an array which is inside another array?

Tags: php

Till now I have been using function `array_values` to put those values inside another variable. But now I've got one array inside another, so I would like to know is it possible to get values of that array just by using function (instead using `foreach loop`)?

Here is code sample of what I'm talking about:

```
public function returnArrayElements() {
  $array_one = ['positive' => [], 'negative' => []];
  $array_two = [1, -1, 2, -2, -3, -4, 5];
  foreach($array_two as $element) {
    if ($element > 0) {
      $array_one['positive'][] = $element;
    } else {
      $array_one['negative'][] = $element;    
    }  
  }

  return [
    'pos' => array_values(array_values($array_one['positive'])),
    'neg' => array_values(array_values($array_one['negative'])),
  ];
}
```

Is using `array_values` function inside `array_values` function legit? Or is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:**

As you can see, this is simplified code, of course I am not using it like this in real situations. The point is that `$array_one` is much bigger and has a lot of different elements, where one of them is another array. Array are being passed as parameters to function where they are being used (I haven't written it that way in my question as I thought it is not important right now). Now imagine that somewhere in the code I need only those values from array which is used as element inside another array, and that is why I need function to return only those elements and not whole `$array_one`, because the part of the code where that function is called knows only how to work with elements from `$array_two`.

Here is a new code sample:

```
$array_one = [
[
  '1' => 'el1',
  '2' => 'el2',
  '3' => [
    '3.1' => 'el3.1',
    '3.2' => 'el3.2',
    '3.3' => 'el3.3',
   ],
   '4' => 'el4',
   '5' => 'el5',
], 
[
  '1' => 'el1',
  '2' => 'el2',
  '3' => [
    '3.1' => 'el3.1',
    '3.2' => 'el3.2',
    '3.3' => 'el3.3',
   ],
   '4' => 'el4',
   '5' => 'el5',    
]];

function one($array_one) {
  //knows how two work with whole $array_one
}
function two(array_values(array_values($array_one))) {
  //knows only how to work with el3.1, el3.2, el3.3
  //in this function is not implemented the code
  //which is going to get those three elements from $array_one
}
```

And I have written same elements inside two different arrays up there, but it is just because I can't think up of something else anymore. In real system those arrays are different, just the `array_key` `3` always has the same name (in real system it's name is not `3`, but `property_data`).

**EDIT 2:**

[Image of real code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtskN.jpg)
I need those **3** elements from `property_data`, all of them put inside **ONE** variable (one array). Is it possible to do that without foreach loop?

Comment: `array_values(array_values` is __totally useless__.

Comment: @PaulCrovella getting elements of an array. And I taught it is possible to get elements of array which is inside another array by double using it.

Comment: Why are people so critic here, you always try to attack before help someone. You all give me minuses instead of trying to understand what I need help with. It's hard to explain the small part of code which is integrated in big system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// will print the first element of $array_two
echo $array_two[0];

> 1
```

Or you can just use print_r():

```
print_r($array_two);

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => -1 [2] => 2 [3] => -2 [4] => -3 [5] => -4 [6] => 5 )
```